# Laravel - base64 to pdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have a base64 text, I can convert it to pdf as I want with the following codes.

```
$decoded = base64_decode($r->labelData);
$file = 'label.pdf';
file_put_contents($file, $decoded);
if (file_exists($file)) {
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
     readfile($file);
     exit;
    }
```

But I want to use it with DOMPDF library. When I use DOMPDF the pdf page returns empty. Where am I missing?

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', ['data' => $decoded]);
    return $pdf->setPaper('a4')->download('labels.pdf');
```

**myPDF.blade.php**

```
<body>
    {{$data}}
</body>
```

Comment: Show us the myPDF view, what you are doing with that $data ?

Answer (score 0):

DomPDF is a html to pdf generator, if you already have the pdf content there is no need for using DomPDF.

Just return the content as PDF:

```
$filename = 'some-filename.pdf';

return response()->make($data, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
]);
```